# How to read a RasterBand as Dataset to use in gdal.Translate as source?

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate, band

I need to translate each band of netcdf file to other format. How can I get raster.GetRasterBand() not as a band object, but as a dataset ot otherwise to use it in gdal.Translate(dst,src) as src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tell `gdal.Translate` which band you want:

```
gdal.Translate(dst,src, bandList=[1])
```

More keyword args you can use are define in the [documentation](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions).

Comment: Thanks, i missed it. I think I should invent an other way as I have to adress to bands by time, but it could work.
Also it seems I have found the way to extract one band with raster.GetRasterBand().GetDataset().